# how to use wrapInner() to wrap a certain content inside ah html tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got HTML code like this:

```html
<ul class="table">
  <li>Height: 70cm</li>
  <li>Width: 100cm</li>
  <li>Depth: 400cm</li>
  <li>Color: yellow</li>
</ul>
```

Now, I would like it to look like this (insert those **span** tags inside; note that there's always a string ":"):

```html
<ul class="table">
  <li><span class="name">Height:</span> <span class="value">70cm</span></li>
  <li><span class="name">Width:</span> <span class="value">100cm</span></li>
  <li><span class="name">Depth:</span> <span class="value">400cm</span></li>
  <li><span class="name">Color:</span> <span class="value">yellow</span></li>
</ul>
```

I've tried something like:

```js
$('ul.table li').html().replace('<li>', '<li><span class=name>');
$('ul.table li').html().replace(':', ':</span><span class=value>');
$('ul.table li').html().replace('</li>', ':</span></li>');
```

But it didn't work. Is this possible to do with jQuery, for example with `wrapInner()`, or another similar method?

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```
$( 'li', '.table' ).html( function ( i, html ) {
    html = html.split( ' ' );
    return '<span class="name">' + html[0] + '</span> <span class="value">' + html[1] + '</span>';
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/gyqCh/

You have to make sure though that each LI contains exactly one space character which should be between those two words.

Comment: Was on my way to this same solution. I'm still surprised at how many jQuery methods accept functions as arguments for manipulating the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('.table li').each(function(){
  var values = $(this).text().split(':');
  $(this).html('<span class="name">'+values[0]+':</span><span class="value">'+values[1]+'</span>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling $.html() simply returns the content, you don't have a reference to the content.

Try

```
var myHtml = $('ul.table li').html();
myHmtl = myHmtl.replace('<li>', '<li><span class=name>');
myHmtl = myHmtl.replace(':', ':</span><span class=value>');
myHmtl = myHmtl.replace('</li>', ':</span></li>');

$('ul.table li').html(myHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do it like this:

```
$('ul.table li').each(function(i, elem){
    var html = $(elem).html();
    var s =  html.split(":");
    var final = "<span class='name'>" + s[0] + "</span>:<span class='value'>" + s[1] + "</span>";
    $(this).html(final );        
});
```

Now one reason it didn't work before was because you were searching for li's inside your `.html()` but since your selector was including the li the `html()` only grabs what's on the inside thereof.